# regional settings date in Excel

Tags: vb.net, date

I got a problem with the date settings on my client system,

My program demands to set the date as DD/MM/YYYY and I used the type as text in the database,

so I am unable to see what was the date format in my client computers regional settings

so if my client computers regional setting is MM/DD/YYYY if while checking the date  criteria in the code problem is occuring

can anyone help me for this problem

Comment: What programming language are you using? If you don't tell us, we can't answer.

Comment: Thnks Guys,

I am using VB.NET and my application is window based application

Answer (score 0):

If you have libc available, you can use strftime to control the format of your date strings.

If you just have text entries in your database and don't know what the original format was, you are basically lost. Date strings representation in the database probably shouldn't be ASCII strings to begin with.

Comment: strtime means what..

I cant get that can you please tell me in detail

Comment: see http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime

If you are not on a linux platform, you'll need to look for the appropriate header file/library.